# ANTLR: Get text representation of a sub lexer rule

Tags: parsing, antlr4

consider the following lexer rules in ANTLR4:

```
ID: [a-z]+;
INT: [0-9]+;
ARRAY: ID '[' INT ']';
```

Is it possible in a tree walking scenario where I have access to `ctx.ARRAY()` (where `ctx` is a subclass of `ParserRuleContext` that was generated out of a parser rule) to get the text representation of the lexer rules `ID` and `INT`?
I currently fetch the whole text representation with `ctx.ARRAY().getText()` and parse the contents of `ID` and `INT` using regexes and was just wondering if there is a 'cleaner' out of the box solution ANTLR provides.

*Note: Because of external dependencies making `ARRAY` a parser rule is not an option.*

Thanks in advance for meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexer rules in ANTLR 4 cannot be broken down into parts. This was a design decision that we made as part of a massive speed and memory improvement for ANTLR 4 lexers over ANTLR 3 lexers. ANTLR 3 lexers were recursive descent recognizers with many of the same features as parsers. In ANTLR 4, the lexer is nothing more than a DFA recognizer with support for semantic predicates, so the boundaries between the individual components of a token are not tracked at all.

You'll have to either make `ARRAY` a parser rule, or separately parse the result of `getText()` when you need to break up the token's text.

Comment: Ok, then I keep my regexes :-)
Thanks for the quick answer.