# Lexer Priority with space

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

Here my grammar.

```
grammar MainGrammar;

mainFile: statement*;
statement: stackStatement NL;
stackStatement: KEYWORD WS INT;

INT: [0-9]+;
KEYWORD: 'def';
SENTENCE: (~[\r\n@:=])+;
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
NL: '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
```

I try for the main rule *MainFile* the code

```
def 123456
```

that match only the text as ***SENTENCE*** token and don't find ***KEYWORD*** token.  Whatever order of token.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are skipping `WS` and `NL`. Therefore the parser doesn't even see the respective tokens. That's why it can't match them (They are not part of the `TokenStream` that is fed into the parser).

In order to fix this you might look into lexical modes or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039472/writing-parser-rules-sensitive-to-whitespace-while-skipping-ws-from-the-lexer)